# Silverlight custom EventTrigger

Tags: c#, silverlight, events, eventtrigger

I am trying to create a custom event to trigger an animation in Silverlight. Although the event is getting triggered, the animation is not working. The following is the relevant code:

```
namespace SilverlightApplication1
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            MyEvent += new ChangedEventHandler(UserControl_MyEventHandler);
            /* Other stuff */
        }
        private void UserControl_MyEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
                MessageBox.Show("MyEventHandler has been called");
        }

        public delegate void ChangedEventHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e);

        private event ChangedEventHandler MyEvent;

        private void UserControl_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
                if (MyEvent != null)
                    MyEvent(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```

The XAML code is as follows:

```
<UserControl
... 
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity" mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="SilverlightApplication1.MainPage" MouseLeftButtonDown="UserControl_MouseLeftButtonDown">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MyEvent">
                <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="Highlighted"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        ...
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Current, the message box containing "MouseLeftButtonDown" is getting displayed but the animation is not getting called. The animation did get called when the EventTrigger EventName was `MouseLeftButtonDown` instead of `MyEvent`. Please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set SourceName in EventTrigger if you want to trigger on event of some control. 
I guess, in your case in code behind:

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(this [or some other object with Highlighted state], "Highlighted", false);
```